# Kendo UI Grid: possible to allow grouping on specified columns and not on other columns

Tags: grid, grouping, kendo-ui

With the Kendo UI grid (as shipped by Telerik) is it possible to allow grouping on some columns yet not on others?  The demo example shows `groupable: true` as a grid-level property. The documentation reads `groupable Boolean | Object(default: false)`. Can the `groupable` property be set to *false* on a column object, to override the grid-level groupability at the column-level?

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
 dataSource: {
     data: createRandomData(50),
     pageSize: 10
 },
 columns: [
     {
         field: "Name"
     },
     {
         groupable: false,    /*  ?prevent grouping on birthdate? */
         field: "BirthDate",
         title: "Birth Date",
         template: '#= kendo.toString(BirthDate,"dd MMMM yyyy") #'
    }
 ],
  groupable: true
```

});

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yay you almost self answered your question. Yes you can, here is sample column definition.

```
 {
        "title": "Birth Date",
        "field": "BirthDate",
        "groupable": false
 }
```

Make sure you use Q3 2012, I am not sure if it is supported in previous versions.

Comment: Interestingly, `columns.sortable` and `columns.filterable` are in the API docs, but `columns.groupable` is not.

Comment: Probably it was recently added and the documentation is not updated.